# Deep association and Sphinx index with Thinking Sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Currently I have the ff table:

```
Teams
id

Team_User
team_id, user_id

Users
user_id

Item
id
team_id
```

And the ff. model:

```
Team
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

User
has_and_belongs_to_many :teams

Item
belongs_to :audit_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id"
```

Why I am trying to archive is to get Sphinx to index all the user_id that associate with Item and I came up with this index definition:

```
  define_index do
    has audit_team.users(id), :as => :team_users
  end
```

I am not sure if this is correct or not. Also it's seam that Thinking Sphinx didn't build the config for this. As I rebuild, reindex and run the app, the ff. error shows up:

```
index ncpar_core: no such filter attribute 'team_users'
```

What could be the problem and how can I archive this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You may need to run ts:rebuild after adding the attribute so Sphinx is aware of it. Also, perhaps it's a typo here instead of in your code, but `id` in the attribute definition should be a symbol:

```
has audit_team.users(:id), :as => :team_users
```