# Thinking Sphinx search using 'with' and indexed attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

**UPDATE:**

Ok so I am no longer getting an error, but I am not getting any results back (even when there is only one search option).

I added the has clause to my list of indexes:

```
  define_index do
    has bar_profiles(:day), :as => :days
    indexes bar_profiles.budget, :as => :budget_tags
    .
    .
  end
```

So my search is:

```
bars = Bar.search(search_options)
```

with

```
search_options = {:conditions=>{:budget_tags=>"LOW BUDGET"}, :with=>{:days=>"thursday"}, :page=>1, :per_page=>20}
```

bar_profiles has rows for budget, experience, tags, day, etc.

Bar has many bar_profiles (potentially 1 for each day)

What I am trying to do is use the thinking sphinx search (in the bar model) to match the users selected criteria for budget, experience, tags against the bar_profile that has the day that matches with "today" (the current day).

This is the last thing I have to do to finish this app and I'm pulling my hair out cause I can't find any examples of how to set this up right...

If you have any insight please post it, anything helps. Thanks.

---

At first I thought my question was similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469864/deep-association-and-sphinx-index-with-thinking-sphinx) with an extra layer of abstraction, but I think my problem is with the search options not the indexing.

First off let me state that I have been having the worse time trying to fix a previous' groups implementation using thinking sphinx. I have finally got the project 90% working and the last 10% deals with being able to get the right filters to check against.

Here is a brief overview. The application has bars and bar_profiles (amongst many other tables that connect to these 2, and users, but they are not necessary to understand this issue.) There can be a bar_profile for each day of the week, for each bar.

So in the bar_profile model there is:

```
belongs_to :bar
```

and in bar there is:

```
has_many :bar_profiles
```

followed by the indexes in bar (written by the previous developer):

```
  define_index do
    # name is a reserved keyword so we need to specify it as a symbol to work
    indexes :name
    indexes tags
    indexes bar_profiles.day, :as => :day
    indexes bar_profiles.tags, :as => :daily_tags
    indexes bar_profiles.budget, :as => :budget_tags
    indexes bar_profiles.experience, :as => :experience_tags
    set_property :delta => true
  end
```

The issue I am having is this current implementation does not constrain the search properly to the current day. Instead of checking the current days profile for the bar, it seems to be checking against ALL the bars profiles.

So I set the current day at the start of the method:

```
today = (Time.now + Time.zone_offset('EST')).strftime("%A")
```

Then I think it needs to be something like below. I referenced [this post by pat](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#filters) about using 'with', but I am not sure if I am messing up the syntax (because I am getting an error):

```
search_options = {:conditions => {}, :with => {:day=>today}, :page => 1, :per_page => algorithm.results_per_page}
```

Then I use these search options:

```
search_options[:conditions][:experience_tags] = options[:experience] unless options[:experience].blank?
budget = combine_budgets(options[:budget])
search_options[:conditions][:budget_tags] = budget unless budget.blank?
```

But when I try to run the search I get this in my development log:

```
^^^^ ERROR! Reason: index bar_core,bar_delta: no such filter attribute 'day'
```

Now I am pretty confused by this since the index for :day was set up as shown above... I'm not sure if 'filter attribute' is different then an index attribute. If someone could please offer some insight into this it would be greatly appreciated (looking at you @pat).

This is the final issue in this app, so if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: I'm not sure if I remember correctly but `attribute_filters` are supposed to be passed to the `:with` option.  `:day` is a field and not an attribute filter so it needs to go to the `:condition` option. Change indexes to `has bar_profiles.day, as: :day` so you can pass it to the `:with` option

Comment: Thank you for the response I will try that right now. Like I said, I am super new to thinking sphinx.

Comment: That fix got the query to run without errors, but it isn't returning any results. Even when there is a profile for that day with the right experience and budget tags.

Comment: did you run `rake ts:index` after changing your `define_index` block?

Comment: yes I did, initially I had it wrong and it was giving me an error when I ran it. But then I followed what you posted and ran the index so it search runs, it just doesn't return anything....

Comment: after above related changes, can u update your question with: define_index block and search query you are doing now...